# Creating Border in Box-like World

Tags: warfare, alternate-worlds

I'm creating a world in outer space. The people live in a box-like structure because outside the planet is uninhabitable. In this box, the houses are built in rows of two or three with 5 columns, in a grid-like structure. On the paths between the houses there are plants and some trees (mainly flowers, I'm not sure which ones yet). 
The government rules over most of their world, but there is a resistance based in a lone house outside the grid of the other houses and which is trying to gain control. 
The government wants to block all connection to the resistance, but I need the resistance to have ways to cross in undetected, as hard as it may be. There isn't much space to hide because it's all houses and very low plants. 
What sort of border would accomplish that? I'm open to border placement ideas, border material, ways for the resistance to camouflage themselves into the government's area or anything really as long as it doesn't require an extreme amount of a hard to transport resource.

Comment: Welcome to World Building, user613.  I think you'll get better quality answers if you provide some additional details.  How does the resistance house physically connect to the rest of the box-world?  How large is this space and how many people?  Level of technology -- does world have cameras and wifi equivalents?  Is the resistance popular -- do they have the populations hearts and minds or are the outcasts with every hand against them?

Comment: It is very unclear what you are asking. A border is the boundary between the territories under the control of two sovereign powers; it may be or it may not be materialized on the ground, depending on the relationship between the two sovereign powers. I do not understand the idea of a border between a resistance movement and the sovereign state they aim to overthrow: after all, a resistance movement cannot possibly have a legal existence.

Comment: I'm confused about the scenario being described here. How many people are we talking about? Is this like... a small town, or a city, or an entire country in this 'box'?

Comment: What is the size of the box? Can resistance dig down into earth? Or is there a "utility" level below the houses, with pipes, rats and sneaky resistance members?

Comment: It sounds like you're recreating the world of Yevgeny Zamyatin's 'We' with the rebel base house from '1984'. Perhaps you should read them.

Answer (score 3):

**Their box is only the top box.**

[image: subterranean rome]

https://www.tripsavvy.com/explore-subterranean-wonders-beneath-rome-1507332

People have been living in this protected box for a very long time.  The government has adjusted the history of its people to meet its needs and so the citizenry is not generally aware of what is beneath them.

It is not easy to get down there, but below the boxes are the boxes and living spaces of previous civilizations, all the way down to the first people who built the original enclosure to protect them all.  Other things they find down there might be useful to advance your plot.

Once you are down there you can move about unseen.  Coming back to the surface might pose its own challenges.

An interesting question: what if what is below them is not just ruins?  Could the lower levels still be inhabited?  And is it possible that their own box is not actually the top box and there are others above them?  How big is their world, exactly?